# Why does SonarQube report: The return value of "format" must be used

Tags: java

I'm getting this code smell in SonarQube *"the return value of "format" must be used"*.

Sample code:

```
ShiftStartDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMddyyy")
ShiftEndDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMddyyyy")):
```

I tried, but I'm not sure what to return.

Comment: It means you have to assign the result of that call to a variable, otherwise you're doing nothing with what is returned by the method you're calling.

Comment: What is unclear about sonar's message?

Comment: sonarqube also provides example of what to do to fix the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`format` is not mutating the Date, but rater returns a new String with the provided pattern. Sonarqube is telling you, that you do nothing with the return value. So either assign it to a variable, which you will use or remove the invocations altogether.